# How can I open /data/data/com.termux/files?

Tags: file-management, termux

I am unable to access the `/com.termux/files` folder. I want to access it because I want to do a change in `writer.js` files.

I tried `cd..` and `cd -` codes to go back to files folder from home folder.

Comment: Does opening Termux and `cd ..` work?

Comment: No it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get to the Termux files folder, you have to CD to the entire path name like this.

```
cd /data/data/com.termux/files
```

From there, you can `cd` into the `usr` folder and wherever you want to go. Once you find `writer.js`, you can edit it using nano which comes with Termux. Enter `nano writer.js`, make your edits, and then use CTRL+O to save it and CTRL+X to exit nano.

Then you can get back to your home directory with:

```
cd ~
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help but can u tell me how can i open writer.js file in termux after into a certain directory.I want to edit writer.js

Comment: @rohitsingh Get a text editor like `vim` or `emacs`.

Comment: How to install them and how to open writer.js with them. By the does it work on Android

Comment: @rohitsingh Mine may be a stupid question, but here goes: why don't you move the file you wish to edit inside your internal storage, edit it with a GUI editor and put it back where it was?

Comment: You install packages on Termux with the `pkg` comand, such as `pkg install vim`. But try `pkg install ne` instead -  it's easier to use. Then type `ne writer.js` and tap Esc to view the menu.